# Bind JNDI datasource in tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, coldfusion, datasource, tomcat6, jndi

Is it possible to bind programatically a DataSource to Tomcat's 6 JNDI?

I want to create a DataSource on the fly and then make it available through JNDI ( to ColdFusion for instance ).

This is what I have:

```
public void bindToConext(DataSource dataSource) throws NamingException, SQLException {
    Context initContext = new InitialContext();
    Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
    envContext.bind("jdbc/mydatasource", dataSource);
}
```

But I'm getting this exception:

```
javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: Context is read only
```

Is there a work around?

Comment: Can you post your `<Resource ` configuration?

Comment: @mindas Hello, I don't have at this point, because I won't put anything there (everything will be created dynamically ). Should I create a fake one?

Comment: I'd try to create a placeholder and then modify entries within it. In either case, this sounds like a good practice. Let us know if this had helped.

Comment: I'm starting to look at http://code.google.com/p/osjava/wiki/SimpleJNDI now.

Comment: At the end that was what we used, SimpleJNDI, but we have to override the `close()` method, for I loses all our info and can't really control when is it going to be invoked.

Comment: You might want to add this as an answer and accept it, explaining it in more details. Future readers will be happy ;-)

Comment: The above mentioned SimpleJNDI project is not under active development anymore. But there is a GitHub clone where you can get a further developed version being actively supported by me. See https://github.com/h-thurow/Simple-JNDI

Answer (score 4):

Well it was not possible because tomcat's context becomes read-only after startup.

So what we did was to use SimpleJNDI which is a in memory context ( more like a glorified HashMap ) and that worked for us.

It needs a `jndi.properties` file that has to be in the classpath and where you define the directory where to look for resources and the initial context factory

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.osjava.sj.SimpleContextFactory
org.osjava.sj.root=some/relative/path
org.osjava.jndi.delimiter=/
org.osjava.sj.jndi.shared=true
```

To make the binding with ColdFusion first we create the data source programatically and then bind it to the context:

```
DataSource ds = ...
Context c = new InitialContext();
c.bind( "jdbc/my/blah/"+var , ds );
...
```

Then using CF admin api we create a CF datasource of type JNDI just using the jndiname

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat's working context is java:comp/env. This context is read-only. But you can create your own contexts, using Tomcat's JNDI Implementation, as long as you keep yourself out of "java:comp/env".

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext()
ctx.createSubcontext("any_name").createSubcontext("any_sub_name");
ctx.bind("any_name/any_sub_name/myDataSource", myDataSource);
```

By default Tomcat's contexts are shared, so the DataSource is retrievable from anywhere in your app this way:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext()
DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("any_name/any_sub_name/myDataSource");
```