# Bind Spring datasource to JNDI

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, datasource, bind, jndi

I have a spring boot based spring application that is deployed into an **external tomcat** instance.

The application creates few datasources. These datasources are added to entitymanager and transaction manager is setup accordingly.

However, recently we have integrated programmatically an ETL tool that works with JNDI datasources. The ask here is to bind the current spring datasources into the JNDI tree at startup.

I have tried to create an initial context post datasource bean creation and bind the datasources there, however, i do see a NoInitialContext exception being thrown.

How can i bind these spring datasources into the JNDI tree of the external tomcat? Appreciate the help!

Note: I cannot/am not allowed to edit the tomcat configuration as it is initialized from a PaaS template. So need to work on the approach of being able to bind to the JNDI tree from within the application.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not possible. Take a look at the JEE spec:

> The container must ensure that the application component instances have only read access to their naming context. The container must throw the javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException from all the methods of the javax.naming.Context interface that modify the environment naming context and its subcontexts.
>   [Jakarta EE Spec - Resources, Naming, and Injection](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jakartaee-platform/blob/master/specification/src/main/asciidoc/platform/ResourcesNamingInjection.adoc)

See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14580286/context-is-read-only) has some interesting code examples if you want to play around.

IMHO you can achieve what you want by creating JNDI resources and passing these to the EntityManger/Spring. But that means that the configuration would exist outside of Spring completely. So this may not do what you want to do.