# How to dynamically/programmatically configure hibernate to use h2 database jndi connection pool?

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, jndi, h2, connection-pooling

Hibernate complained about the connection pool. First, I tried to use the [Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/jdbc-pool.html).

This required a resource configuration in the context.xml:

```
<Resource
  name="jdbc/mydatasource"
  auth="Container"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
  username="user"
  password="pw"
  driverClassName="org.h2.Driver"
  url="jdbc:h2:path/to/db/dbname" />
```

The problem I always have with the xml configuration files is that the database location/url changes depending on development/test/production. I also don't like the cleartext user/pw.

So I was wondering how to do this programmatically during webapp startup.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out to wrap the H2 DataSource with a Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool, but I found that H2 ships it's own connection pool and DataSource implementation:

```
// JdbcConnectionPool implements DataSource
org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcConnectionPool connectionPool = JdbcConnectionPool.create(dbUrl, user, pw);
// java:comp/env is read-only, create subcontext that is writable
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734391/bind-jndi-datasource-in-tomcat
new InitialContext().createSubcontext("mywebapp").bind("datasource", connectionPool);

org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.datasource", "mywebapp/datasource");
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", H2Dialect.class.getName());
```

Hibernate seems to be happy now.